# Performance issue on client side using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm just toying around with a simple multiple upload form that is designed for images. What I'm working on at the moment is a multiple upload form that sends an AJAX request before the user submits the form. The PHP script simply saves files to the server and resizes the images.

When the request is sent, a span is created with an image element inside that has an id corresponding to the image number in the list, and an ajax loading gif is placed in the source.

When the response comes back, I get the element by it's id, and replace the source with the image saved on the server.

Everything so far works fine, it's just incredibly slow.

full code here: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mJNbLH9x)

where I'm almost positive the problem's occurring,

```
        xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if( xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200){
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
                
                var actualNumber = jsonResponse.imageNumber-1;
                
                console.log("Image #" + jsonResponse.imageNumber + " Took " + jsonResponse.scriptTime + " to process.");
                console.time('profileGetElementByIdforImage'+actualNumber);
                document.getElementById("preview"+actualNumber).setAttribute("src", jsonResponse.fullPath);
                console.timeEnd('profileGetElementByIdforImage'+actualNumber);
            }
            
        };
```

The strange thing is, if I take this off of the local machine and upload it to my server, it takes even longer, even though the PHP script times are considerably shorter.

I'll get something like this:

> Image #1 Took 6.3307409286499 secondsto process.
>
> profileGetElementByIdforImage0: 3ms

And even though the source within the actual html has changed when I click to inspect the element, the ajax loading gif still remains for a bit...

I thought it might have something to do with the browser having to adjust the images, so I added a "thumbnail" feature to the php script. But the client-side took just as long as when I was using full sized images.

So now I'm wondering, does this have anything to do with requests from the server? Or is this a DOM issue?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PHP image parsing and especially resizing takes quite a while especially if the image is quite big. So if 6 seconds is the amount of time it took to send the POST request, resize and return the image that is quite good.

To make things a little bit faster I would suggest throwing the POST request in a aSync process a naive way of doing this would be:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  //POST Request
},1);
```

Then once the image comes back simply put it where ever you want this will make user experience better and will not halt the browser from doing other things therefor it will seem quite fast.

Comment: Hmm.. Thanks, but the post requests already run asynchronously. Images do not come back in the order they were sent. The problem seems to be once the images get back, there's another 15seconds or more of waiting, even though the image source has been changed in the DOM.

Comment: hmm very weird. Have you tried checking the timeline in chrome dev tools?